# Getting an error while creating customer profile in authorize.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net

I am creating the Customer Profile in which i want to store shipping address of customer.
For this the code is -

```
  customer_profile_request = CreateCustomerProfileRequest.new
  customer_profile_request.profile = CustomerProfileType.new(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email)[0,10], user.full_name, user.email,nil,nil)
  full_address = user.customer_addresses.primary_address.try(:truncate_full_address) || 'Address'
  customer_profile_request.profile.shipToList = CustomerAddressType.new(user.first_name, 
    user.last_name, nil, full_address, 
    user.customer_addresses.primary_address.city, 
    user.customer_addresses.primary_address.state, user.customer_detail.zipcode, nil, nil, nil)
  customer_profile_response = initialize_transaction.create_customer_profile(customer_profile_request)
```

And i am getting an error -

"The element 'shipToList' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'firstName, lastName, company, address, city, state, zip, country, phoneNumber, faxNumber, email' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'."

Am i missing something?